# SVN Requires Lock

Tags: svn

How do you turn off Requires-Lock for every file in a SVN Repository and all future files that get added to it?

Comment: Is this related to the "svn:needs-lock" property? There might be more here: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.locking.html

Answer (score 3):

It's off by default. You can recursively remove the property on all files in a working copy:

```
svn propdel svn:needs-lock --depth=infinity
```

Normally new files don't get the property set automatically. It was probably configured to as an auto-prop.

See `$HOME/.subversion/config` (linux) or `%APPDATA%/Subversion/config` (Windows). Look for auto-props, to see if svn:needs-lock gets set.